# Acceder a método de un webservice.svc desde jquery

Tags: jquery, html5, ajax

Tengo un `WebService` al que quiero acceder a sus métodos, he buscado pero no he encontrado una solución de como atacar al servicio `.svc` solo encuentro servicios `.asmx`.

Desde [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) agrego la referencia de servicio y para usar el método hago lo siguiente:

```
ServicioClient SClient = new ServicioClient();
Gestores_SesionResponse sesionRespuesta = null;
Gestores_SesionRequest datosSesion = new Gestores_SesionRequest(){
  Pwd = model.Password,
  UserName = model.UserName
};
SClient.dbGestores_Sesion(datosSesion, out sesionRespuesta);
```

Pero quiero atacar al mismo servicio desde [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), he intentado de la siguiente manera:

```
$.ajax({ 
  url: 'http://nombredominio.com.mx:1234/Service.svc/dbGestores_Sesion',
  data: '{"UserName":"usuario","Pwd":"123456"}',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  method: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  processdata: true,
  success: function (data) {
    console.log("exito");
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function (result) {
    console.log("error");
    console.log(result);
  }
});
```

Pero al hacer la peticion me manda `error 400`

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://nombredominio.com.mc:1234/service.svc/dbGestores_Sesion. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:50478' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

Donde `dbGestores_Session` es el nombre del método, y recibe 2 parámetros usuario y contraseña, entonces ¿Cómo puedo acceder al método de mi `WebService.svc` desde [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)?¿Y como puedo obtener los datos del `out` que uso en [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)con [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)?

**Nota:** Si accedo a http://nombredominio.com.mc:1234/service.svc me muestra la pagina del servicio pero si accedo de esta forma http://nombredominio.com.mc:1234/service.svc/dbGestores_Session solo muestra una pagina en blanco

Comment: Trata de agregarle el valor `*` o `true` a **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En tu `Web.config` dale la siguiente configuración:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>    
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>   
</system.webServer>
```

En caso te salga el siguiente error:

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error del IIS

y el origen sea la línea donde se encuentra:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
```

Ve al Web Platform Installer, encuentra e instala "**URL Rewrite**", es el módulo del IIS que se necesita.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: he modificado la `url` a `http://nombredominio.com.mc:1234/service.svc/json/dbGestores_Sesion` después de hacer unos ajustes al webservice, intente nuevamente si la configuración y lanzo el mismo error, cuando puse la configuración nuevamente salio correctamente, solo evite las lineas `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/><directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>` ya que lanzaban el error que mencionas, intente la instalcion pero lanzo error en la instalación así que evite esas dos lineas